# ¿Se puede usar php 7 en wampserver2.4 win xp 32 bits?

Tags: xampp, php7, wamp, localhost

hola a todos ante todos gracias por su atención mi problema es que no tengo una pc capas de correr windows7 y por ende no puedo instalar ni wampserver, ni xamp u otro programa similar por lo menos en versiones modernas la ultima que he podido instalar es la de wampserver2.4 pero todos mis proyectos estan en php 7 intente actualizar pero si bien me aparece la verion7.3.3 de php al seleccionarla el icono de wamperver se queda en naranja y nunca me inician los servidores he escuchado que pudiera ser por window xp ¿alguien sabe como solucionar el problema?

Answer (score 0):

Hace tiempo averiguando un poco descubri que no hay forma de instalar php 7 en win xp por cuestiones de compatibilidad

Comment: Esto realmente no responde a la pregunta, por favor lee [answer]

Comment: Creo que la pregunta no corresponde a algo específico de programación.